# Piece-wise continous vs $ \in L^2(a,b)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces

Let us say I have a function $f$ that is piece-wise continuous in the interval  $[a,b]$ and is not $\infty$ at any point in this interval can we then say with $100\%$ certainty that $f\in L^2_w (a,b)$ for some finite weight function $w$. Is the reverse also true, such that if $f\in L^2_w(a,b)$ then $f$ is piece-wise continuous in the interval $[a,b]$ and is finite in this interval?

Comment: The converse is almost certainly false. For example, there are many $L^2(a,b)$ (with weight function constantly $1$) functions which are discontinuous everywhere; the characteristic function of the rational numbers is such an example.

Comment: What do you mean by finite weight? Certainly, $f\in L^2_w(a,b)$ for $w=0$, but that does not seem too interesting.

Comment: @MaoWao Simply one for which $w(x)<\infty \forall x \in [a,b]$

Comment: There is always a weight $w$ such that $f\in L^2_w(a,b)$ (namely $w=0$), and if $f\neq 0$, there is a weight $w'$ such that $f\notin L^2_w(a,b)$ (take an appropriatley shifted version of $1/x$).

Comment: This is not true in general. It is true, however, if you assume $w(x) \leq C$ for all $x$ and some fixed constant $C$.